# Avoiding ambiguity with 'owed' - technical terms

Tags: terminology, ambiguity, technical, disambiguation

I want to make a spreadsheet including money I am owed and money I owe. How do I avoid ambiguity with the word 'owed'?

e.g.

> **money owed** - money that is owed to me
>   **money <strike>owed</strike>** **?** - money I owe to other people

I don't want to phrase the terms as above (unbolded) because it would seem awkward and lengthy.

What's a good, technical/formal (hopefully monetary) alternate term to differentiate between the two

Comment: What about ***money lent*** and ***money borrowed***?

Comment: @user067531 Good, but my request concerns money that hasn't been transferred yet; ***lent*** suggests that money has been given temporarily and vice versa.

Comment: I see, but I think that “I owe money“ still implies  that money has already been transferred.

Comment: @user067531 [owe: Have an obligation to pay](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/owe) i.e. not been paid yet.

Comment: If you have an obligation it is because you have already received something, it may be money, a service, goods etc.

Comment: Can 't you just make the titles "money i'm owed" and "money I owe"?

Comment: @KillingTime I'd like a technical term.  I'll make that clearer

Comment: @user067531 Yes, but if you are owed money, you are waiting to receive it.

Comment: The amounts of money you owe to other people are your **debts**.

Comment: With "owed" you must somehow specify or imply who is doing the owing.

Comment: @WeatherVane - But the amount of money owed to you by other people are their debts.  Without specifying (or implying via context) whom you're talking about, any terminology is ambiguous.

Comment: @HotHicks I thought about that but forgot to mention it. If it is a spreadsheet about *my affairs*, then the debts are mine. Similarly if a column is headed "owed" then that must mean "what I am owed." Just as a column headed "receipts" can only mean: received by me.

Comment: I don’t see how there can possibly be a way to differentiate them, because they’re **exactly the same thing**. From the point of view of the money (which is the relevant one here, since it’s the money you’re using as the header and modifying with an adjective), there is only the state of being owed – the direction of owing is a property of the debtor/debtee, not of the debt itself. So if you want to distinguish them in a spreadsheet, I’d say you’d have to find a way to use the distinguishing entity (you) as the header.

Comment: "Obligation" comes to mind as money that you owe, but I can't find a reasonable antonym.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Receivable** and **payable**. These are basic accounting terms defined in many places, including this one: https://www.rasmussen.edu/degrees/business/blog/basic-accounting-terms-acronyms-and-abbreviations-students-should/

In other words, you don’t have to be a CA or CPA to use them.

Comment: These are the proper terms. +1

Comment: Thank you.  This is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the legal terms for the people involved in this case would be *debtor* (one who owes a debt) versus *debtee* (one who is owed a debt).  In both cases, a debt is owed, so -- as you note -- *owe* is ambiguous, as is *debt*.  In legal terminology, who owes whom is usually denoted by the *debtor/debtee* distinction.  One could also use *debtor* vs. *creditor* in similar fashion.  Therefore, one way of distinguishing could be "debts owed" versus "credits due," but I'm not sure even that is clear without reference to **the specific *person* who is owed** in each case.

Anyhow, I don't know how you'd want to phrase that in a spreadsheet, but I believe that's as close to "technical terms" as you'll get.

Comment: “Credits owed” – does that even make sense? Can you owe credit (except in the sense of thanking someone)? Wouldn’t _debts owed_ and _credits due_ be less confusing? Those are at least unambiguously different, and if we make the very reasonable assumption that both relate to a ‘me’, then they’re also opposites and appropriate here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Good point; I'll modify accordingly. I was just trying to use OP's terminology. But these still aren't unambiguous without a clear reference to a person: Are "debts owed" *to* me or *from* me?  Are "credits due" *to* me or *from* me? I'll admit without context that "to" is the more reasonable construction, but with just *debts owed* vs. *credits due* as the only words, it's still ambiguous.